# Textarea to paragraph or plain text

Tags: php, jquery, textarea, paragraph

I have a form where a user is able to comment via a textarea. If the submit button is clicked it returns the value of what is entered in the textarea inside a textarea. How can I change this it so that on submit the value of the textarea is returned as a plain text/paragraph with jquery or php?

The code for textarea and button:

```
<textarea rows="6" cols="40" scroll="auto" name="reply_for_{$item.id}">
    {if isset($item.reply)}
        {$item.reply}
    {/if}
</textarea>
<br />
<input name="addcomment" value="{lang mkey='submit'}" type="button" onclick="
    document.forms['commentsFrm'].id.value={$item.id};
    document.forms['commentsFrm'].submit(); 
"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 2 answers solved partly the problem. However It gave me some new inspiration and I solved it like this

```
{if $item.reply == ''}
<form name="reply" method="post" action="reply">
    <textarea id="txtreply" name="txtreply" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="btnAdd" value="{lang mkey='send'}" />
</form>

{else}

{$item.reply}

{/if}
```

Thanks everybody for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="addcomment"]').on('click',function(){
     var comment = $('textarea').val();
     $('textarea').remove(); // removes the textarea
     var actContent = $(this).parent().html(); // get the actual content of the parent dom node.
     $(this).parent.html('<p>'+comment+'</p>'+actContent); // you set the new html content for the parent dom node

});
```

So this would take the textarea content and save it into a paragraph. A bit akward solution but it should do the magic.

Comment: Hi, both answers seem to work till the page is completley refreshed. The textarea disapears for a short while and returns again. however I did find a solution by adding {if} {/if} statement in the page. So when reply = empty it shows an textarea or else the value of reply. So this solves my problem. Not the way i was looking for but it just works fine. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this, but here's what comes to mind:

```
$('input[name="addcomment"]').on('click', function() {
    var textArea = $('textarea[name="reply_for_{$item.id}"]');
    var text = textArea.val();
    $('<div id="no-editing-me">').text(text).insertAfter(textArea);
    textArea.hide();
});
```

If you give your elements IDs, you won't have to worry about all that `[name="reply_for_{$item.id}"]` gunk in the jQuery. It'll be faster, too.